# Prove that the following function $f(x)=\log_{2}\left(x+{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$ is invertible on the whole number line.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, special-functions, inverse

I think that it would help to show that this function is odd. But how can I show that the function $$\log_{2}\left(x+{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also directly use that an explicit formula for the Area sinus hyperbolicus is
$$
\text{Arsinh}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})
$$
since
$$
x=\sinh(y)=(e^y-e^{-y})/2
$$
can be written as quadratic equation
$$
0=(e^y)^2-2e^yx-1=(e^y-x)^2-(1+x^2)
$$
with the only positive solution
$$
e^y=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\implies y=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You just have to prove it is strictly monotonic.  Can you determine the sign of its derivative?

Comment: The derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\ln 2}$. How would you prove that $f'(x)>0$ for every $x$?

Comment: Simplify this expression!

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(x\sqrt{x^2+1}+x^2+1)\ln 2}$?

Comment: Why did you develop the denominator?

Comment: I multiplied numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2+1}$. I am sorry but could you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your result is not false. Simply you shouldn't have developed the denominator if you want to simplify.

Comment: I see! $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\ln2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\frac{1}{\ln 2}$!

Comment: Thank you all of you. It helped so much.

Comment: How did you calculate exactly the derivative of the function?

Comment: @Cauchy the Dog: Your answer is now usable. You also might have observed that, if there was a natural log instead of the binary log, you obtain the inverse function of $\sinh x$.

Answer (score 2):

Check that $x+\sqrt {x^2+1}$ maps $\mathbb {R}$ bijectively onto $(0,\infty).$ Then recall $\log_2 x$ maps $(0,\infty)$ bijectively onto $\mathbb {R}.$ It follows that the composition is a bijection of $\mathbb {R}$ onto $\mathbb {R},$ which gives the conclusion.